# How to call MS Graph Search API for get SharePoint list items using react applicaiton

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to call Microsoft graph search API or Graph API to get SharePoint list items using React Application (Single page application).

Comment: take a look at [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#single-page-applications) and find a suitable sample

Answer (score 0):

You can follow  the [doc](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/blob/main/2-Authorization-I/1-call-graph/README.md#explore-the-sample) to setup and call graph API in your react app,

Use below code snippet to get [SharePoint list items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/listitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript)

```
getGraphClient(result.accessToken)
        .api('/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}? 
         expand=fields')
        .responseType(ResponseType.RAW)
        .get()
```

Comment: Hi Vicky , Thanks for your response , can you please let me know how I can pass multiple filters using Search API or above API call. i am getting below error.                                                         GEThttps://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/286b086a------4b25-ab89-63fa681743c3/lists/d3e45e69-------4023----44f488d60bcb/items?$filter=fields/Title eq Test 3&expand=fields
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 319ms]

Comment: have you tried with query - await client.api('/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}?expand=fields')
 .get();

Comment: Actually ,i want use Serch API call using POST method . please let me know have any sugession